# A/C compressor Switches of at the same time as the Fan motor

Tags: ac, lexus, fan, compressor

I have a Lexus IS250 2008 the a/c compressor switches off the same time as the fan motor blower. Cant seem to find a fix, the blower motors are new just bought and switched. Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: If you are referring to the radiator fan then that seems normal to me.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with @vini_i here ... that seems completely normal to me. If the radiator fan does not need to be running when the A/C kicks off the fan won't be running at all. It doesn't run unless needed. When the A/C compressor is running there has to be air flow through the condenser in order for the A/C to work inside the vehicle. If the coolant system doesn't need cooled, there's no reason for a fan to be running after that, so it's allowed to shut down. No fan needed: no fan running.